# How to keep kafka topic message?

Tags: apache-kafka

my team are developing kafka, using CDC with debezium connector.

The CDC was clear and no problem, the problem is how to keep kafka message for specific topic ?

Any idea for the configuration kafka retention for specific topic ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set `retention.ms` (or `retention.bytes`) config on a per-topic basis. Cf https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs